# How to find an object in all T-SQL scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ERP Database and it is big. One of the table gets updated by an SP, TRIGGER, FUNCTION or something else. Because, I watched the Profiler to find UPDATE or INSERT statements but I couldn't find ant UPDATE or INSERT. Therefore, the table should be updated by SP, TRIGGER, FUNCTION or something else.

Is there a helper to find in which SP,FUNCTION OR TRIGGERS the table is used? I want to give the table name and it will tell me where the table name is used?

Comment: RedGate has a free SQL Search tool that integrates into management studio - it's quite nifty for quickly finding column names in various other objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS do the following

> Server->Database->Tables-> tablename ->right click -> view
>   dependencies

select **Object that depends** on radio button to view the object's that were using your table

Answer (score 0):

Export all script objects to a file and search the file.  You can do this from SQL Server Management Studio.  Right Click the database and go to Tasks > Generate Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS you can right click a table and then choose 'view dependencies' or use sp_depends.